# Why this one last line in SQL make difference

Tags: sql

I'm trying to select some parts of exposure of ads

Have 2 similar SQL codes, just one line difference but the out put are different

code1

```
select req.bucket
,imp.expo_freq
,imp.platform
from some_adform imp
left join some_other_adform req
    on imp.requestid=req.requestid
where req.lineitemid!='something'
;
```

code2

```
select req.bucket
,imp.expo_freq
,imp.platform
from some_adform imp
left join some_other_adform req
    on imp.requestid=req.requestid
;
```

The only difference between these two parts are obviously 
(where req.lineitemid!='something') , then the expo_freq from table of imp are different. But after checking,in the table some_other_adform req the 'something' doesn't exist at all, that means it should of influence anything! then why does this line influence the answer of the SQL?
BTW, if I put the line inside the req form the result will be same as code1
code 3 looks like this

```
select req.bucket
,imp.expo_freq
,imp.platform
from some_adform imp
left join (select * from some_other_adform where req.lineitemid!='something') req
    on imp.requestid=req.requestid
;
```

Comment: The `WHERE` clause contains an additional restriction.  Would would you _not_ expect the two queries to have different behavior?  BTW...you might want to move the logic in the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause of the join.

Comment: May I know more details of the additional restriction? I moved the where clause to the on clause on code 3, but didn't get the point why they are different,thank you for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

Because when putting the statement in the where-clause, it means there has to be row in the table that is left-joined for the statement to evaluate - in effect making it an inner join.

If you put it as a condition in the left join (as AND ...), it is evaluated only on the matching rows in the table that is left joined:

```
select req.bucket,imp.expo_freq,imp.platform
from some_adform imp
left join some_other_adform req
  on imp.requestid=req.requestid
  and req.lineitemid!='something';
```

As a side-note, if you added a NULL-check, you would get the same:

```
select req.bucket,imp.expo_freq,imp.platform
from some_adform imp
left join some_other_adform req
  on imp.requestid=req.requestid
where ISNULL(req.lineitemid,'')!='something';
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `NULL` fails the condition in the `WHERE` clause turning the outer join into an inner join.

This is normally fixed by moving the condition into the `ON` clause:

```
select req.bucket, imp.expo_freq, imp.platform
from some_adform imp left join
     some_other_adform req
     on imp.requestid = req.requestid and
        req.lineitemid <> 'something';
```

`NULL`s can be a bit confusing.  Almost any comparison returns `NULL` which is treated as false in a `WHERE` condition.  This is as true of `<>` as of `=`.

Comment: `WHERE NULL <> 'foo'` is false ?

Comment: @Cid . . .No, it is `NULL`, which is treated as false in `WHERE` conditions.

Comment: Okay, hence the `IS NULL` condition

Answer (score 1):

> But after checking,in the table some_other_adform req the 'something'
>   doesn't exist at all, that means it should of influence anything!

This is not correct.
You are doing a `LEFT JOIN`, so many rows from the table `some_other_adform` may not match so they will be filled with `null`s.
The condition:

```
where req.lineitemid!='something'
```

removes `null`s also because comparing anything against `null` results to `null`, so the condition in the `WHERE` clause is **not** `true` and the row is not returned. 
Try with:

```
where req.lineitemid!='something' or req.lineitemid is null
```

this will produce the result you want.